# Compile iOS projects on Ubuntu?

Tags: ios, ubuntu

Is it possible to compile my Objective-C iOS-specific project on anything other than OSX? I spend a lot of time in Windows and it'd be less of a hassle if I could, at the very least, SSH into my Ubuntu machine and edit code / compile on there. I think the only thing I'd need the Macbook for would be editing storyboards and running the iphone emulator.

I just have a lot of free time every day, but don't have access to my Macbook until I get home around 7pm. Are there any good ways to remotely work on an XCode iOS project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is, although you'll need a jailbroken device for this. You are also going to need to [build the opensource, non-official toolchain for yourself](http://code.google.com/p/iphonedevonlinux/), or [get a precompiled version.](http://xsellize.com/topic/111034-toolchain-for-ios-42/)

Hey, you can even make GCC run on your iPhone itself (that's how I use it).

Answer (score 1):

Why not SSH into the Mac and use the command-line tools that come with Xcode?

Or, more comfortably, just remote into the Mac via one of the many remote desktop solutions out there (TeamViewer is free for personal use and quite good at poking through NATs etc., but there are a lot of other options) and use Xcode.